# Add asterisk when number is in range

Tags: java, arrays

this is my first time using this site so sorry if I do something wrong,

Here's an example output of the program I'm working on, basically what's supposed to happening

```
1-10     |**
11-20    |****
21-30    |***
31-40    |
41-50    |******
```

It goes on like that till the range of 91-100. This is my code so far, I've had a couple of different ideas so the code is incomplete in some parts but I really don't know which direction to go.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HowMany
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {  
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        
        int range1 = 0; 
        int range2 = 0;
        int range3 = 0;
        int range4 = 0;
        int range5 = 0;
        int range6 = 0;
        int range7 = 0;
        int range8 = 0;
        int range9 = 0;
        int range10 = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Enter integers between 1 and 100 (inclusive).");
        System.out.println("Enter an integer out of the range to stop.");
        
        //Assigning the user input a variable
        int userNum = input.nextInt();
        
        while(userNum >= 1 || userNum <= 100)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
                System.out.print("*");
                if(userNum >= 1 && userNum <= 10)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated and if I haven't mentioned anything that I should specify let me know

Thanks

Comment: Do not use 10 variables like that, use an **array**, and use division to calculate the index into the array. If you haven't learned about arrays yet, then now is a great time to learn.

Comment: lol I'm currently learning about arrays should've realized this, thanks

Comment: Are yo reading multiple user inputs or only one number? In your question provide both input and output cases so that people will not have to infer the problem statement. :)

Comment: there can be multiple or just one, there's no limit, basically as long as the user enters a number bigger than 0 and less than 101 it goes on

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be beneficial for you if I just write you the program because this looks like exercise or homework, so let's work this out together. The program should run like this:

1. USER INPUT
2. If: 1..100 => PUT in the correct range and do 1)
3. Quit

The first observation is that

```
    int userNum = input.nextInt();
```

needs to happen inside a loop, called the [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). The structure is one big loop, that does the steps as stated above.

Now there is a better way to keep track of the ranges. Whenever you see yourself writing variables like var1, var2... you are better off with an array of values. The best would be to use an array of integers, where each index represents one range, something like this:

```
    [0] 1-10
    [1] 11-20
    [2] 21-30 ...
```

and then you can just increment the correct index.

For instance, the user types in 34, you work out with [the modulo operator](https://www.baeldung.com/modulo-java) where it goes and insert it.

Then I am sure you can find a smart way to print the final string. The best would be to create a separate print function for the array, something like:

```
    printCounts(int[] count) { ... }
```

Hope those help, feel free to ask follow-up questions :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a good foundation to start off I'll get back to you if I run into any trouble

Comment: '3. if input >100 QUIT'    '4. GO TO step 1.'

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the incrementing, I've made an array and a loop but I don't know where or how to add to the values in the array

Comment: Ok, sure.
So you're starting out with an array where all indices are 0. Each index represents a different range (see answer above). So if the user inputs 42 for instance I can calculate (42 - 1) / 10 = 4 (integer division) so I know that it is the range with index 4 (41..50), therefore I increment (=add 1 to) the array on that index, like:
        counter[4]++;
the array keeps track of how many * need to be printer per range. (by the way, please accept my answer if you find it useful :))